# Float left and right in same UL

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a unordered list

```
<ul id="smart-menu">
    <li class="left">item 1</li>
    <li class="left">item 2</li>
    <li class="left">item 3</li>
    <li class="right">item 4</li>
    <li class="right">item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I want the items to be displayed horizontal. The items with the left class on the left site and the others on the right site.

I want to use [smartmenus](http://www.smartmenus.org/), for this reason I need a unordered list.

Here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/GhgAWHv78qerLDcKgKDm?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of my understanding from your post, this is your desired result

```css
.left{float:left}
.right{float:right}
ul{list-style:none}
```

```html
<ul id="smart-menu">
    <li class="left">item 1</li>
    <li class="left">item 2</li>
    <li class="left">item 3</li>
    <li class="right">item 4</li>
    <li class="right">item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the problem with float : right is that item4 and item5 are in wrong order

Comment: I have added a plunk and tried your solution but with smartmenus it does not work

Comment: I have added !important to left and right, now it works with smartmenu

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box if you can have a "filler" element between left and right.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
.filler {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="smart-menu">
  <li class="left">item 1</li>
  <li class="left">item 2</li>
  <li class="left">item 3</li>
  <li class="filler"></li>
  <li class="right">item 4</li>
  <li class="right">item 5</li>
</ul>
```

check out this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJpBjq

and here is a [guide to flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I have added a plunk and tried your solution but with smartmenus it does not work